# Add Quantity Input Field on WooCommerce Checkout For Each Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product-quantity

I am trying to understand how I can add the quantity input field on the checkout page and that way, allow the customer to change the quantity for each product.

**This is what I got so far:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'qty_and_qty_change_on_checkout', 20, 3 );
function qty_and_qty_change_on_checkout( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    return '<br>
    '.woocommerce_quantity_input().'
    <span class="product-quantity">
    ' . sprintf( '<b>Qty:</b> %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '
    </span>';
}
```

But this gives me an error even though `woocommerce_quantity_input()` is the official function for it? **The error is:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: product in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 1670
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed to set necessary arguments into `woocommerce_quantity_input()` function just like in [`cart/cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/cart/cart.php) template file… The following will display an input field with the current quantity in checkout page replacing the quantity string:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'qty_input_field_on_checkout', 20, 3 );
function qty_input_field_on_checkout( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];

    if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
    } else {
        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
            array(
                'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                'min_value'    => '0',
                'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
            ),
            $_product,
            false
        );
    }

    return '<br><span class="product-quantity"><strong>' . __( 'Qty') . ': </strong></span>' . $product_quantity;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Now this will only allow to display the quantity field, but will not not allow to update the product quantity, as it's something else much more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, very kind of you to help. I managed to get the change to auto-update.

Comment: How can I get this to auto-update with AJAX when the quantity is changed? The user mentioned being able to achieve this but didn't share. Very frustrating because I'm at a loss.